# Relative layout params in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-relativelayout

I am trying to set `relative layout params` programmatically. I can set `params` using java but not know how to accomplish using **kotlin**. So what I have tried is as follows :

**MainActivity class**

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var context : Context
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: android.os.Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        context=this
        asdasd.text="finaly done";
   var  param:RelativeLayout.LayoutParams =//don't know what to do here
            val i:Int=1
            var temp :TextView = TextView(this);
            temp.id=i              
            temp.layoutParams = param ;
            temp.text= "TextView"+i
            Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "onCreate: " + i)


    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: probably `=RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`  then `param.addRule(...)`

Comment: i know but in kotlin how can i declare it .. thats what i want

Comment: declare it where?, you can show your java code the way you want it in kotlin

Comment: sorry friend i am directly  coding in kotlin not in java .

Comment: `how can i declare it .. thats what i want` please explain?

Comment: means i want declare `param` variable  as `Layoutparams`. and want to set in `textview`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160611/discussion-between-divyesh-kalotra-and-pavneet-singh).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It work for me::

```
    var  param: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,100);
    param.setMargins(500,12,0,0)
    val i:Int=1
    var temp : TextView = TextView(this);
    temp.id=i
    temp.layoutParams = param ;
    temp.text= "TextView\nadfadsfasdfadsfasdf\nadfadsfasdfa\nadfadsfasdf"+i
    Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "onCreate: " + i)
```

See here ouput Generated by it: [image: Output of Above code]

Thanks and let me know if you need more.

Comment: Thanku soo much divyesh

Answer (score 1):

```
    lateinit var r1: RelativeLayout
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       r1= RelativeLayout(this)
       var rlp : RelativeLayout.LayoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var view: RelativeLayout =RelativeLayout(this)
view.layoutParams= RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(25,25)
```

Try This one ...

Comment: Nice and simple, just like how we used to do it in java. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is Working for me

```
var tempSnack = Snackbar.make(view,"Your Text Here", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            var tempview = tempSnack.view
            var params = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP
            tempview.layoutParams = params
            tempSnack.show()
```